# Visual Studio Secrets File

Tags: c#, .net

Currently running VS 2022 with .NET 7.x.

I am trying to implement user secrets. I must have gone through over 100 pages online via Google to figure this out, but everyone's setup seems to differ from mine.

Basically I have a simple app, the ONLY time it connects outside my machine is via MySQL through a connection. It doesn't use docker, or any other http libraries.

A lot of the guides mention placing stuff inside a start.cs file, which I don't have. All I have is a `program.cs`.

Other docs mention adding your secrets via CLI and it will auto-add them to secrets.json; which I've done, but then they throw in an appsettings.json file; which I also don't have. That file seems to be created when doing certain web based projects.

I'm just trying to figure out how to add user secrets for my simple application just so I can secure the mysql connection details in a string.

Some of the examples I've found reference code such as:

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true);

var config = builder.Build();
var connectionString = config["ConnectionString"];
var emailHost = config["dbpass"];
```

But in my case, I don't have the `appsettings.json` file, all I have to work with is a secrets.json file with the secret inside:

```json
{
  "dbtest": "223AFFA325674A...",
}
```

Pretty much all I'm looking to do is just reference the "dbtest" secret, and plug it into my code.

I've tried almost every example I've found online. And as I said; all the examples I've found, seem to reference files that are generated when you're creating web-based apps. Whereas mine is just a standalone Windows program with a simple mysql query function.

Comment: `"appsettings.json"` is idiomatic to .NET Core (2016) and later , but you're using .NET Framework 4.x (2010). Is there a reason you can't migrate to a recent .NET version (e.g. .NET 8?) So-long as you remain on .NET 4.x you'll be increasingly excluded from the changes and improvements made in later .NET versions.

Comment: In a WinForms project, you use `appsettings.config` which is an XML file. There is no built-in support for _secrets management_ in .NET Framework 4.x. That said, secrets-management libraries are still largely intended for web-applications, not desktop applications - on the desktop, just use DPAPI to store per-machine or per-user data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection

Comment: @Dai Sorry, to specify, using Framework 7.0, and on VS2022. No idea why I put 4.8. I was running .NET 8, however numerous libraries were not compatible.

I think that's where most my issues are coming from is it seems most tutorials are for older versions which included startup.cs; which I've read is no longer a thing, and has been merged with program.cs And then the mention of the appsettings file; which seems to be auto-generated for projects with web-based apps.

Comment: What is your end goal? You can just deploy an appsettings.json file with a non-web-app. Do note that you cannot hide secrets from end-users this way. If their machine connects to your MySQL server directly, they can debug the application and see where it gets its secrets.

Comment: So I think I'm getting confused by the two references. There's my project which is using .NET 7, however, there's also .NET framework 4.8.1. I need to read up on the differences between the two.

Comment: @Arthae yes, that knowledge is vital. Some time ago Microsoft introduced .net Core as a rewrite of .net Framework. Both platforms were supported in parallel up to Framework 4.8 and Core 3.1. Then .Net 5 came out as the new common successor. It was mostly based on Core. You can still write in the old frameworks, or even write an library that supports multiple frameworks, but that's just making live hard on yourself. (Note I let out .net Standard. It's obsolete now, so forget it ever existed ;) )